# die like autodie

Tags: perl, methods, autodie

I use [`autodie`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/autodie) to handle exceptions from built-ins. Unfortunately its scope is lexical,  `autodie` does not work with methods.  Is it possible to throw exceptions from my class methods so that they are handled in the same manner like autodie exceptions. In short, I dont want users of my classes to handle exceptions in two ways - one with the rich exception class that autodie provides for built-ins and another for the simple "`die if ...`" that my code throws.

If it helps, I use [`Moose`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Moose) to build my classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your exceptions to be like those in autodie, then I can think of two options:

**Use or inherit from the `autodie::exception` class.**

This is pretty straightforward, just `perldoc autodie::exception` and note which arguments it needs when creating new objects.  You might find that inheriting from `autodie::exception` provides you more flexibility or functionality, in which case you should do that.

**Tell `autodie` to use your own exception class.**

This is a little more tricky, but not that hard:

```
# Inside my/autodie.pm

pacakge my::autodie;
use parent 'autodie';

sub exception_class { return 'my::exception::class'; }

1;
```

You can then use `my::autodie` in your code (with lexical scope), but whenever it throws an exception, it will create and throw an object from `my::exception::class` rather than from `autodie::exception`.  This is probably overkill for what you want, but it's very handy if you want to, say, extend `autodie`'s exceptions to provide stack-backtraces, localisation, or other functionality.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Looking at the `autodie` source, I see that it dies using:</strike>

```
    Carp::croak sprintf(
        ERROR_WRONG_FATAL, $Fatal::VERSION, $VERSION, $autodie_path
    );
```

If you do the same from your code, I would expect the calling code to receive something looking the same.

**Edit:** As pointed out in comments on this answer, `autodie` actually dies from within `Fatal`.  A five-minute look over the `Fatal` source failed to turn up how/where *it* dies, mostly just making me confused over the relationship between the two modules.[1]

Unless you want to go digging through the `Fatal` source, your next option would be to define what features of the `autodie` exceptions are important to you and duplicate them.  From the question, it sounds like this could be as simple as identifying the exception class used by `autodie` and throwing exception objects of that same class.

[1] `Fatal` has a lot of "use autodie instead because it does this thing that Fatal doesn't" comments, but `autodie` seems to delegate pretty much everything to `Fatal`, so it would appear that the things `autodie` does which `Fatal` doesn't are still actually done by `Fatal`...

Comment: You're looking in the wrong place.  That code is what gets executed if `autodie` is unable to load the correct version of the `Fatal` module, which is where the real magic happens.

Comment: Thanks.  I have temporarily created a subclass of Exception::Class::Base manually and defined attributes similar to autodie::exceptions. Am testing this ....